# Adding content to a post request without javascript

Tags: html

I want to let a user leave an anonymous comment on a post. Right now it's super simple, the HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="/comment" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="text" value="test"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But I also want to include the id of the parent post in the post request (Unless there's another way of telling what post the comment was made on). Otherwise there would be no way of telling what comment belonged to what post. Is this possible without Javascript?

Comment: Could you use a hidden input field and set its' value to the id of the parent post. That way it could be submitted with the rest of the form.

Comment: If you're using a url scheme like `/post/1234`, then you could `/post/1234/comment` with your comment in a POST method like you have the `form` and get it from the URI.

Comment: Adding a hidden input field worked well.